# id field not persisted in couchbase database

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

I'm picking an id field from a `JSON` request body, though I can log it to the console I cant persist it to another couchbase document.
I used `@JsonProperty("id")` for the id field in the DTO class but with no luck. Any other field from the request body works fine.
Any advise.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.